# Error compiling assets on heroku production site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline, assets

I've been working on a site that suddenly stopped compiling /most/ assets. I found the syntax error (I was missing a semicolon towards the top of the page) and fixed it, but the heroku production site is still detecting it. Assets won't load, and I get this error when I run `heroku run rake assets:precompile`

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected "}", was ""
  (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):505
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1189:in `expected'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1125:in `expected'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1120:in `tok!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:658:in `block'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:409:in `media_directive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:222:in `special_directive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:197:in `directive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:675:in `block_child'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:668:in `block_contents'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:125:in `stylesheet'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:41:in `parse'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:406:in `_to_tree'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in `render'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:24:in `evaluate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace
```

Has anyone had this issue? I have tried commenting out `config.assets:compile  = true` in production.rb and running `heroku run rake assets:clobber`, but the issue still occurs...

Comment: Your issue is a syntax error, not anything with rpecompiling.   The key line here is "Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected "}", was ""
  (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):505",  It looks like in one of your sass files there is a bracket missing on something.  What it is saying is that it expected a "}" but instead there was "" which equals nothing and so there is a bracket missing somewhere.

Comment: A file with a syntax error got compiled at some point, and I'm trying to get it out of the system @RockwellRice

Comment: have you tried compiling your assets in your computer ?, you might get the same error.

Comment: Yes, everything is fine locally @fanta